# How do I create a property on a custom silverlight behavior so that expression blend will display the object picker?

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend-4

I've created a custom behavior with a target control property and I can't figure out how to get blend to display the round "object picker" so that I can drag and drop to target a particular control.  So when I create a behavior like this:

```
    public class SetFocusAfterBusyBehavior : Behavior<BusyIndicator>
    {
        public object TargetControl { get; set; }
```

When I try to set the TargetControl property in blend I just get a box with no object picker.

I've tried changing TargetControl to be a dependency property.  I've looked at the TargetedTriggerAction class in reflector to see if I could figure out how if there is a special attribute.  I also poked around on the web and read this [blog](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/11/17/silverlight-design-time-extensibility.aspx) which doesn't specifically mention the object picker and also seems like a lot more work than should be necessary.

Is there a simple solution to this?  I'm pretty new to silverlight and blend so perhaps I'm missing something very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CustomPropertyValueEditorAttribute` from the `System.Windows.Interactivity` assembly in combination with one of the value from the `CustomPropertyValueEditor` enumeration, to get access to some of the provided property editors.

```
public class SetFocusAfterBusyBehavior : Behavior<BusyIndicator>
{
    [CustomPropertyValueEditor(CustomPropertyValueEditor.Element)]
    public object TargetControl { get; set; }
```